# sed and escape chars

Tags: bash, ubuntu, sed

How does `sed` operates with special symbols? I'm trying to

This is my script (it fixes Qt project file under Ubuntu, 'cos Ubuntu doesn't have qt-multimadia):

```
OldInclude='QT       += multimedia'
NewInclude='
       INCLUDEPATH += //usr//include//QtMobility
       INCLUDEPATH += //usr//include//QtMultimediaKit'

find -iname "*.pro" -type f -exec sed -i "s/$OldInclude/$NewInclude/g" {} \;
```

In file:

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2013-03-07T02:19:23
#
#-------------------------------------------------
QT       += multimedia
QT       -= gui
TARGET = MultiItem
TEMPLATE = lib
DEFINES += MULTIITEM_LIBRARY
SOURCES += multiitem.cpp
//Even more lines here
```

But it replaces nothing - it looks like I do something wrong with input strings.

How to replace them exactly? The file I'm going to update is following:

Comment: You should provide an example file (or an excerpt) for which it fails to substitute.

Comment: Don't use `/` for your `sed` delimiters if your patterns contain `/` characters.

Comment: @CarlNorum I've replaced "s/$OldInclude/$NewInclude/g" with "s@$OldInclude@$NewInclude@g". It works, but replaces nothing :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the \n character in your replacement if you want sed to put in a newline:

```
$ OldInclude='QT       += multimedia'
$ NewInclude='\nINCLUDEPATH += /usr/include/QtMobility\nINCLUDEPATH += /usr/include/QtMultimediaKit'
$ sed "s@$OldInclude@$NewInclude@g" your_snippet.txt
```

Produces the result I think you want.